# Where are mldonkey-server config files?

Tags: 14.04, server, bittorrent

I have installed mldonkey-server with

```
sudo apt-get install mldonkey-server
```

It was installed and running. Neither telnet localhost, nor web interface availabe.

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 4000
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Telnet connection from 127.0.0.1 rejected (see allowed_ips setting)
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Now how to check it's config? I can't find where is it. It is said in manual, that mldonkey configs are in the same place where application installed. But I don't control this place while using apt-get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was in /var/lib/mldonkey for me

[image]